# SVN Externals and Revision Association

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I would like to use SVN externals to share code files between different projects. I need to ask you a question concerning that feature, but let do it by explaining the situation.

1. I created two projects (directories) on the SVN: 'A' and 'B'.
2. 'A' contains files to be shared among other projects and one of them is named 'shared.txt'.
3. The 'shared.txt' is linked to 'B' (using the svn:externals property of 'B').
4. Apart from that, the 'B' contains other source code files (a full project).

Now the question. I checked out some older revision of 'B' to find out which revision of the 'shared.txt' I would get with it. **And unfortunately, no matter which historic revision of 'B' i downloaded from my test repository, I always got the latest version of the 'shared.txt' with it.**

Let's imagine that I want to download project 'B' from before several months. During these months the 'shared.txt' underwent many changes. But I want to download a complete project as it used to be several months ago, together with externals as they were at that specific time.

**Is that possible without manual looking for an appropriate revision of each single external?** I know I can associate specific versions of externals to my test project 'B', but this is no solution. I guess that if I do that, I will never have access to up-to-date externals, even when I check out the latest revision of 'B'. Am I right or wrong?

Thank you for your help (sorry if my question has already been asked, but I could not find any similar one).

Comment: I also need a solution to this problem and started a discussion on the svn users maillist leading to the following feature request.
http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this form of question was asked some time ago here (smth. like "When svn up -r {DATE} in superrepo URL, use *this date* for externals update, if they are HEAD-linked"), it still haven't good answer

Discovered anwser was "You have to `cd` into all externals WC /directory-externals/ and `svn up -r {DATE}` for getting synced state". I haven't answer for file-repo

**Alternative solution**

More actions in process of development, less action with time-back

- Always define externals with PEG-revision
- Monitor commits (thus - changing top-revision) into external
- After external-commit perform changing of external definition with additional commit (maybe it can be scripted in post-commit hook for repo-external)

FR for ASF "recursive processing of subrepos for {DATE} operations in master repo" will be useful